# さくらのVPSにてポート番号を指定してログインできない

Tags: ssh

さくらのVPSを契約しましたが、ポート番号を指定してログインができなくて困っております。どなたかご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。
http://weble.org/2011/05/16/sakura-vps-and-centos
ここの通りに進めていましたが、同じようにしてもエラーが出ることがあったので、少しやり方を変えて進めました。以下に実施した手順を記述します。
＊ここでは仮に、userid:hoge、password:admin1、passphrase:admin2、IP:111.11.11.111とさせていただきます。また、指定されているターミナルにて起動できないことがあったため、実際に使用したターミナルも追記しています。

１・adduserとpasswdの設定（さくらのVPSのターミナルにて）

```
adduser hoge
passwd hoge
New password: admin1
```

２・bashrcは変更せず。
３・vimはあらかじめ（自分のパソコンのターミナル）に入っているため設定せず
４・SSHのポート番号を変更（さくらのVPSのターミナルにて）

```
su
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

この中のポート番号を変更して保存、再起動して異常なし。
　Port 10022　
５・公開認証鍵でSSH接続（自分のパソコンのターミナル）

```
ssh-keygen
generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key(/User/hoge/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

ここでは何もせずにEnter

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase ): admin2
Enter same passphrase again: admin2
```

その後、.sshを作成

```
cd ~
mkdir .ssh
```

その次の「ローカルから.sshフォルダの中に対して以下のようにしてファイルを転送」ができなかった（time outする）ため、自分で保存。

```
/Users/hoge/.ssh
```

に移動してから「is_rsa.pub」を展開。

```
:w authorized_key
```

として保存。
６・転送が終わったらサーバー側にてパーミッションを調整

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

ここでは「サーバー側で」と書いてあったため、これを（さくらのVPSのターミナル）で実行すると、

```
chmod: cannot access : no such file or directory
```

と表示されたため、（自分のパソコンのターミナル）にて実行。何も表示されず。
７・公開認証鍵のみでのログインできる状態に変更するため、ファイルの編集（さくらのVPSのターミナルにて）

```
su
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

以下の通り変更。

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no（なぜか２行あったため削除して１行に）
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

その後、SSHの設定を反映

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

これらの設定をした後に

```
$ ssh -l hoge -p 10022 111.11.11.111
```

とすると、

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

と表示され、ログインすることができません。（どちらのターミナルでも）
解決策として次のページの通りにしました。
http://qiita.com/youcune/items/2f427979403771f2e03a

```
/var/log/secure
```

とすると

```
No such file or firectory（自分のパソコンのターミナル）
bash: /var/log/secure: Permission denied（さくらのVPSのターミナル）
```

と表示されます。

以上です。正直なところプログラミングに関して知識が浅く、単純に勘違いしている点も多いかもしれませんが、そういう点についてもご指摘いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「自分のパソコンのターミナル」で操作しているのが自分のパソコンなのか、そこからリモートでVPSを操作しているのか判別できません。どちらにしても矛盾があります。

VPSを運用される前に、VirtualBoxなどを使って手元に環境を用意して十分なスキルを身につけられることを強くお勧めします。それぞれの操作をする目的と意味は確実に理解している必要があります。インターネットに直接公開されたサーバで侵入被害等にあうと踏み台に使われて他人に迷惑をかけることになりますし、攻撃元として自分が疑われることにもなります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ミスがいくつかありそうなのと、参照先が若干不親切なので、
[さくらVPSの初期設定とCentOSによるWEBサーバー環境構築まとめ](http://qiita.com/junki0605/items/6ce3df1933ef6d31ddfa)
を参照した方が分かりやすいかと思います。

余談ですが、IPアドレスの例示には「192.0.2.x」（xは1～254）のような例示専用のものがあるので、そちらを使った方がよいでしょう。（[参照](http://equj65.net/tech/documentationip/)）

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。お教えいただいたサイトのやり方の通りに進めたところ、無事に最後まで問題なくインストールすることができました。phpとmysqlの設定もするつもりでいたので助かりました。また、例示専用のアドレスについても次回から活用させていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

プログラミングとは関係ない話題のような気がしますが……

手順5の最後、

> ```
> :w authorized_key
> ```
>
> として保存。

この通りだとすればファイル名を間違えていますよ。
authorized_key ではなく、 authorized_keys です (末尾のs)。また、手順に保存を実行した時のユーザーやファイルパスが示されていないのですが、

- VPS 上のユーザー hoge で
- *ホームディレクトリ*/.ssh/authorized_keys に保存されている
  (ここで、*ホームディレクトリ* は /home/hoge (~ や ~hoge という記法もあり)。)

必要がありますが、そこは大丈夫ですか？
続く

> ６・転送が終わったらサーバー側にてパーミッションを調整
>
> ```
> chmod 700 ~/.ssh
> chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```

も、ユーザー hoge で行う必要があります。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。keyはここに書き写す際にタイプミスしたものです、申し訳ありません。また、どちらも「ユーザーhogeで」行う必要があるとのことで、見落としていた可能性があります。今後、気をつけていきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。